# Why do I have None ('NoneType' object is not iterable) when I expected a list?

Tags: python, pandas, nonetype, read-sql

I am retrieving a list of table names using pandas.read_sql and then trying to use a "for" loop to drop tables from the retrieved list. However, I am getting a 'NoneType' object is not iterable error (although the list is not empty).

```
print(type(out_tables_list))
<class 'list'>
print(out_tables_list is None)
False
```

```
tables = pd.read_sql("""
SHOW TABLES IN P_SMO_INP_T
""", con=connection)

tableName = tables.tableName
out_tables = tableName[tableName.str.contains('_sg_')]
out_tables_list = out_tables.to_list()

for name in out_tables_list:
    pd.read_sql("DROP TABLE P_SMO_INP_T.{}".format(name), con=connection)
```

Can you please help me figure out what's my mistake? Thank you in advance!

LE: See below the full output I am receiving:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-1e7a629dac7d> in <module>
      1 for name in out_tables_list:
----> 2     pd.read_sql("DROP TABLE P_SMO_INP_T.{}".format(name), con=connection)

c:\users\sgulunga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    481 
    482     if isinstance(pandas_sql, SQLiteDatabase):
--> 483         return pandas_sql.read_query(
    484             sql,
    485             index_col=index_col,

c:\users\sgulunga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize)
   1726         args = _convert_params(sql, params)
   1727         cursor = self.execute(*args)
-> 1728         columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
   1729 
   1730         if chunksize is not None:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: what line raises the error ?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. The question should be "why do I have `None` when I expected something iterable, like a list?" As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @azro The last line raises the error 

`pd.read_sql("DROP TABLE P_SMO_INP_T.{}".format(name), con=connection)`

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `read_sql` will execute an SQL command and *build a dataframe from the returned rows*. What are the returned rows from a `DROP TABLE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DROP` query returns nothing, so `None`, and so pandas can't iterate on that to build a dataframe.

See [How do I drop a table in SQLAlchemy when I don't have a table object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229140/how-do-i-drop-a-table-in-sqlalchemy-when-i-dont-have-a-table-object/37095265)

---

Note that when debugging be careful about the line raising the error, you said "although the list is not empty" but the line raising the error doesn't use the list

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I know how to fix it. Rookie mistake from my side.

Comment: @SergiuSRG: Please accept the answer. It gives azro some rep and tells others your question is answered.